# Get Fetch Request

Tags: javascript, fetch

I might be overlooking the obvious but is there a way to get the fetch request? (not the response).

A normal fetch looks like something this:

```
fetch(url, {
                method: method,
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Authorization': token,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }),
                body: payload
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                
                console.log(responseData);
            })
```

I want the ability to get the method, headers, body, and are data that are passed to fetch in a variable that can be passed around to other methods like a log.

Comment: But you already have that information in `method`, `token` and `payload`...? I have no idea what you're asking. I'm also having a hard time understanding what you wrote; maybe you could read it over and fix the spelling / grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the request information from a [`Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) (the thing the promise from `fetch` is fulfilled with), but you can build a [`Request` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) yourself, pass it around, and then use that with `fetch`. The `Request` constructor accepts the same parameters `fetch` does, but instead of doing the operation, it just returns the `Request` object for it.

For instance, here's your code done that way:

```
// Building the request, which you can then pass around
const request = new Request(url, {
    method: method,
    headers: new Headers({
        "Authorization": token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }),
    body: payload
});

// Using it
fetch(request)
.then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) { // Don't forget this part!
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then((responseData) => {
    console.log(responseData);
});
```

*(Aside: Note the slight addition to the first fulfillment handler above, to handle the `fetch` API footgun. `fetch` doesn't reject its promise on HTTP errors, only network errors; you have to check for HTTP errors yourself. More in my blog post [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).)*